# How to query a foreign key column with NHibernate, without retrieving the related entity

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

Say I have two classes: `Parent` and `Child`. A `Parent` has a property `Children`, which is of course a collection of `Child` objects.

`Child` doesn't have a `ParentId` property. It does have a `Parent` property.

So, my NHibernate mapping for `Child` includes:

```
<many-to-one name="Parent" class="Parent" column="ParentId" cascade="save-update" />
```

And my `Parent` mapping includes:

```
<bag name="children" access="field" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
    <key column="ParentId" />
    <one-to-many class="Child" />
</bag>
```

Now here's what I want to do: I want to get all the `Child` objects with a certain `ParentId`. I know I can first get the `Parent` and then return its `Children` property. But what if I'd want to query the `Child` table directly?

If it would be a mapped property (for example, `Name`), I could use NHibernate's criteria, but in this case, `ParentId` isn't mapped.

I tried using something like:

```
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Parent.Id", 1));
```

But that doesn't work. I resorted to using SQLCriterion (as explained [here](http://petermorlion.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-use-nhibernates-sqlcriterion.html)), but a friend/colleague got me thinking there must be a better way.

Any ideas? Something with projections and `Restrictions.EqProperty`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this using query over.  Here is an example:

```
Child foundChild = 
    session.QueryOver<Child>()
        .Where(x => x.Parent.Id == 1234).SingleOrDefault<Child>();
```

Comment: This gave me the cleanest SQL (see my comment on Jamie Ide's answer), although the difference isn't too big.

Comment: This will throw an exception if it finds more than one child for a parent. Change SingleOrDefault to List to return all the children of a parent.

Comment: True, I did use List: session.QueryOver<Child>().Where(x => x.Parent.Id == 1234).List()

Answer (score 6):

You have to alias the association path. This will return a proxy for Parent assuming that are using lazy loads. You can access the parent's Id property without triggering a load.

```
return _session.CreateCriteria<Child>()
    .CreateAlias("Parent", "parent")
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("parent.Id", parentId))
    .List<Child>();
```

Comment: This works, but joins to the Parent table and selects all the mapped columns. Cole W's answer doesn't, resulting in a cleaner SQL statement. That's why +1 for this answer, but Cole W's is marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done via Criteria like this:

```
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Parent", Session.Load<Parent>(1));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me the following exception: Type mismatch in NHibernate.Criterion.SimpleExpression: Parent expected type MyDomain.Namespace.Parent, actual type Castle.Proxies.INHibernateProxyProxy_4. This could be specific to our project, YMMV.